# Cannot recognize the type of data returned by api get call for image

Tags: reactjs, file, encoding, base64

I am making an api get call and getting an image as the response.
What I want to do is to convert this image data to a file object, exactly like the one you get from a type file input of a form, but I cannot figure out what kind or type of data is the one that the api is sending, so I can research how to convert it.
At fist I thought is base64 string, but seems that the conversion methods from base64 to file do not work for it. I will attach a screenshot with the api response.
Can anyone tell me what it is and how can I convert it to a file ?
[image]

If i make the api get call with postman I see the actual image as the response

Comment: It’s most likely a PNG image.

Comment: @DaveNewton And how can I convert it to a file like the one you get from a file type input?  I cannot seem to find how

Comment: in the upper left of your screenshot you see a placeholder for an unprintable character followed by the letters 'PNG', so it's probably a PNG file. What you see is just binary data, i.e bytes. Just read the bytes and write them to a file (opened in binary mode) and give it a filename with the png extension, then you should have (hopefully) a readable image file.  Regarding base64: if the data is base64 encoded, you would only see alphanumeric characters and maybe some '+' and '/' in it, e.g. 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA...'